# How to validate if all values are quoted in a .csv file

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have thousands of .csv files and I need to check if all of them has their values QUOTED.

I tried getting them all into a list of dataframes and tried my luck with a very bad code. I need help with this !

```py
def csv_list(folder):
    path = r'C:\\'+folder+'' # use your path
    all_files = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")
    li = []
    for filename in all_files:
        df = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=None, header=0)
        li.append(df)
    return li

def check_doublequotes(csvfile):
    if (csvfile.QUOTE_ALL == True):
        print("csv are double quoted")
```

I got the following error

`AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'QUOTE_ALL'`

Comment: what if only some line (at the end of the file) within a huge csv files has unquoted value?

Comment: Basically, This is a test. It should log a message like 'csv validation failed'

Comment: How do you know if the value is quoted ? Is it a bool column, is it plain quote or double quote inside every single column... please, provide a [mcve]. Here, if we want to 'stupidly' answer your question, we should just say that your condition `QUOTE_ALL` is not correct and should be defined another way.

Comment: Basically, what you would do is : Read the CSV. Check if the CSV completes the test. And put that result back into another template : the test results (dataframe, json, database, the format choice is yours).

Comment: when `pandas` read data from csv then it removes quotas because they are not needed to work with data. They are not part of data but only information for where is begin and end of colum which may have comma or other special char. The same is with module `csv`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you like to check whether your file is consistently quoted, you can do it in two ways. The first is to load all into the memory and then check the consistency. The other is to use converters. In case you want to save memory, this might be an option.

## Loading all into Memory

The first possibility works as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import csv

# 1. read the file without removing the quotes (all colums will be string)
df= pd.read_csv('yourfile.csv', sep=';', dtype='str', skipinitialspace=True, quoting= csv.QUOTE_NONE)

# 2. now check that all fields are doublequoted:
#    the .str.replace below is called to remove
#    trailing spaces from the fields (behind the quotes)
#    the spaces at the beginning are removed by pandas (because of skipinitialspace=True)
df.apply(lambda ser: ser.str.startswith('"') 
                     & ser.str.replace(r'\s+$', '').str.endswith('"')
        ).all().all()
```

Testcode:

```
import io

raw_csv='''""; "Col1"; "Col2" ; "Col3"; "C12"; "index"
"0"; "Bob"; "Joe"; "0.218111"; "BobJoe"; "1"
"1"; "Joe"; "Steve"; "0.849890"; "JoeSteve"; "2"
"2"; "Bill"; "Bob"; "0.316259"; "BillBob"; "0"
"3"; "Mary"; "Bob"; "0.179488"; "MaryBob"; "3"
"4"; "Joe"; "Steve"; "0.129853"; "JoeSteve"; "2"
"5"; "Anne"; "NaN"; "0.752859" ; "NaN"; "-1"
"6"; "NaN"; "Bill"; "0.414644"; "NaN"; "-1"
"7"; "NaN"; "NaN"; "0.026471"; "NaN"; "-1"'''

df= pd.read_csv(
        io.StringIO(raw_csv), 
        sep=';', index_col=[0], 
        dtype='str', 
        skipinitialspace=True, 
        quoting= csv.QUOTE_NONE)

print(df.apply(lambda ser: ser.str.startswith('"') 
                           & ser.str.replace(r'\s+$', '').str.endswith('"')
              ).all().all())
--> True
```

You can also make your output a bit more detailed, if you like. E.g. if you remove the quotes around `Bob` in line with id `"2"` you get, the overall result `False` (of course) and:

```
df.apply(lambda ser: ser.str.startswith('"') 
                     & ser.str.replace(r'\s+$', '').str.endswith('"')
        ).all(axis='index')
-->
"Col1"      True
"Col2"     False
"Col3"      True
"C12"       True
"index"     True
 dtype: bool

df.apply(lambda ser: ser.str.startswith('"') 
                     & ser.str.replace(r'\s+$', '').str.endswith('"')
        ).all(axis='column')
-->
"0"     True
"1"     True
"2"    False
"3"     True
"4"     True
"5"     True
"6"     True
"7"     True
```

## Using Converters

The version with converters works as follows:

```
# define a check function (a converter from string to bool):
def check_quotes(val):
    stripped= val.strip()
    return stripped.startswith('"') & stripped.endswith('"')

# create a converter dict (just use a dict comprehension 
# if you don't know the column names, just make sure you
# chose a range at least as large as you have columns in
# your files (if your range is larger, it doesn't hurt)
conv_dict= {i: check_quotes for i in range(100)}
df= pd.read_csv('yourfile.csv', sep=';', index_col=[0], converters=conv_dict, quoting= csv.QUOTE_NONE)

# if the file is consistently quoted, the following line prints True
df.any().any()
```